# How can I wait until both ajax requests done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is a simplified of my code:

```
var res = array();

$.ajax({
    url: 'test1.php',
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        res[1] = data.result;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'test2.php',
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        res[2] = data.result;
    }
});

if ( /* both ajax request are done */ ) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // wait 
}
```

As you can see I've used `async: true` to run those ajax requests at the same time *(in parallel)*. Now I need to wait until both requests done. How can I determine an ajax request is done? If not wait until it get done?

Comment: By the way, there's no need to explicitly say `async: true`. That's the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use promises:

```
Promise.all([
  $.ajax({ url: 'test1.php' }),
  $.ajax({ url: 'test2.php' })
])
.then(([res1, res2]) => {
  // Both requests resolved
})
.catch(error => {
  // Something went wrong
});
```

Comment: Hmm .. seems nice, upvote. Just can you please tell me what are *promises* do exactly and when should I use them?

Comment: @MartinAJ, this may be useful https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises. A Promise is basically an object that represents a future value, in this case a response. `Promise.all` runs promises in parallel, and `.then` gives you the values _iff_ both resolved successfully.

Comment: I see, thank you. Just why didn't you write `success` block in ajax requests? I should write them, right?

Comment: The `success` and `error` callbacks are not recommended anymore since `$.ajax` returns promises now you can handle the callback in the `then` block as you can see.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you again. And I will be appreciated if you write your code as individually syntax. Currently you've written ajax requests as an array in `promise.all`. Can you please write them separately and then use them in `promise.all`? Like the first example in the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) you provided. I'm just trying to understand *promises* completely.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)** function. It will be resolved if all of the promises is resolved and pass the data as array to the `then` function, else it will be rejected with the first promise failure value

```
Promise.all([
  $.ajax({ url: 'test1.php'}),
  $.ajax({ url: 'test2.php'})
])
.then(results => {
  // results is an array which contains each promise's resolved value in the call
})
.catch(error => {
   // The value of the first rejected promise
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use callback function as well.

```
var res = [];

function addResults(data) {
    res.push(data);
    console.log('Request # '+res.length);
    if ( res.length >= 2 ) {
        // do stuff
        console.log('both request has done.');
    } else {
        // wait 
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    success: function (data) {
        addResults(data);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    success: function (data) {
        addResults(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. upvote. However I think you need to put your function into a loop. Currently what happens when `else { // wait` block executes? Don't need to call it again til `res.length >= 2` be true?

Answer (score 0):

this official document could help you.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

example:

```
var res = [];
$.ajax({
    url: 'test1.php',
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        res.push('Ajax one is complete');
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'test2.php',
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        res.push('Ajax two is complete');
    }
});
var resALL = function(){
    console.log(this)
}
//After the requests all complete 
$(document).ajaxStop(resALL.bind(res))
```